# index.html file is not loading on my express server

Tags: express

I am not able to load my HTML files present in my directory. I am only able to load the default express page. The code given below is for 2 files index.js and index.html. Both the files are present in the same directory.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const app = express();
 app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.headers);
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.end('<html><body><h1>This is an Express Server</h1></body></html>');

});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
<title>This is index.html</title>
<body>
<h1>Index.html</h1>
<p>This is the contents of this file</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[This is the output I am getting. I want to load my index.html not this default page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21j4v.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

keep your **index.html** on the **public** folder not in the root directory.
Like this:

```
public
     index.html
index.js
```